# What's the meaning behind a JS function having functions itself?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Take the following code:

```
let myObject = {};
myObject.someFunction = function(){return 'sample function';};
myObject.someFunction.someOtherFunction = function(){return 'this somehow works';};
```

I can then run both `myObject.someFunction()` and `myObject.someFunction.someOtherFunction()` just fine.

What is the logic and implications behind this working? How is a function able to have methods?

Comment: Every function is an object in JS.

Comment: *"How is a function able to have methods?"* Because functions are objects, and objects can have properties added to them, and properties can refer to functions (because...functions are objects :-) ).

Comment: Re the dupetarget, your `myObject.someFunction` is the analogue of jQuery's `$`.